# Error exporting MySQL query to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data to a cdv/xls file using PHP. I keep getting the following error:

*"Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in"*

Here is my code:

```
<?php


//Connect the the database 
require('../mysql_connect.php') ;

$select = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = 'info@example.com'";

$export = mysql_query ( $select, $dbc ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
{                                            
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
    {
        $value = "\t";
    }
    else
    {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
}
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";


?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: According to the error message, `$dbc` is not a valid MySQL-Link resource so that would mean your problem originates in `'../mysql_connect.php'`

Comment: I understand that and I have tried everything to rectify this but nothing seems to work. I use that exact mysql_connect.php file for my entire website and it works. But for some reason on this page it does not. Any ideas why?

Comment: You would need to post that script (without any login information) so that people here can take a look.

Comment: You also can use SELECT statement with INTO OUTFILE clause. In this case MySQL will export table's data into CSV file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mysqli and not mysql in my mysql_connect.php include. Thanks for the help!